# react change button icon with font awesome unicodes

Tags: reactjs

**Watch.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Watch = () => {
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)

    const toggleVideo = () => {
        setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
    }

    return (

        <button id='play' onClick={() => toggleVideo()} className='fa'>{isPlaying ? '&#xf04b;' : '&#xf04c;'}</button>
    )
}

export default Watch
```

Here I have a simple function that toggles the isPlaying state and changes the button's icon, but the icon is not being displayed instead the unicode is, I tried setting it's innerHTML but it threw errors and said that it is null, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX does not allow HTML entities as strings, [it will escape those values](https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html).

```js
// It displays "First &middot; Second"
<div>{'First &middot; Second'}</div>
```

From the page I linked above, one option is to use [unicode escape values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences) (e.g. `'\uXXXX'`) instead:

```js
<button id="play" onClick={() => toggleVideo()} className="fa">
    {isPlaying ? "\uf04b" : "\uf04c"}
</button>;
```

Answer (score 1):

as you said its not working with `innerHTML`
i tried like this its working.

```
<button id='play' onClick={() => toggleVideo()} className="fa">
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `${isPlaying ? '&#xf04b;' : '&#xf04c;' }`}} />
</button>
```